# Make a smoother plot of functions with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The following code gives me a plot which is not very smooth. It looks like several points (with spacing 0.5 in the horizontal direction) are drawn first and then connected by straight lines. What options do I have to modify to make it smoother? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scale=0.8,
axis lines=middle,
grid=major,
xmin=-5,
xmax=5,
ymin=-5,
ymax=5,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-4,-3,...,5},
ytick={-4,-3,...,4},
tick style={very thick}
]
\addplot[domain=-6:6, blue, ultra thick] {x^3-x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Set the option `samples=<number>`

Comment: @PaulGessler (initially `25`)  Also it is advantageous to use an odd number of samples for a symmetric domain to have 0 included.

Comment: Since you are using only the domain [-2,2] you can set it so to use more samples in that domain

Answer (score 5):

You can use the option `smooth`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scale=0.8,
axis lines=middle,
grid=major,
xmin=-5,
xmax=5,
ymin=-5,
ymax=5,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
xtick={-4,-3,...,5},
ytick={-4,-3,...,4},
tick style={very thick},
smooth
]
\addplot[domain=-6:6, blue, ultra thick] {x^3-x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: smooth plot]

Answer (score 2):

I find easier the macros in the `tkz-fct` package in order to plot graphs

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5]
\tkzGrid[color=gray!40,line width=0.2pt]
\tkzDrawX[color=black,label={$x$},above left=5pt]
\tkzLabelX[color=black]
\tkzDrawY[color=black,label={$y$},below right=5pt]
\tkzLabelY[color=black,orig=false]
\tkzFct[domain=-2:2,color=red,line width=1.5pt]{x**3-x}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]